# Laravel 5.2 upload big image gives TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

Tags: php, laravel-5, csrf

I get csrf error when upload big image. I have `{!! csrf_field() !!}` inside of blade.
I searched about this, and people write "increase upload_max_filesize...", but I increased it to 5M(checked with `phpinfo`) and I don't want to set up more. I have php 5.5.9.
I also have `'file'=> 'sometimes|image| max:5000',`

When I add 6M file it shows

```
FileException in UploadedFile.php line 235:
The file "55.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 4096 KiB).
```

When I add 12M file:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

Any ideas how to catch that error and show to user an appropriate error message?

Comment: post_max_size is 8M

Comment: Both `FileException` and `TokenMismatchException` are extending the generic `Exception` so you can just use `catch (Exception $e)`